# What is variant types in ui5?

Tags: sapui5

In [ui5 guidline](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/docs/guidelines.md#naming-conventions), there is a variant types in naming conventions:

> vVariant : variant types

What is the definition of it?

I find that in doc of [MessageManager](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.message.MessageManager):

> Param: vMessages
>
> Type: sap.ui.core.message.Message
> or
> sap.ui.core.message.Message[]

Comment: FYI: The naming conventions are part of the guidelines you *have to* follow **if** you contribute to the OpenUI5 framework. You don't have to follow them as an app developer if e.g. the customer has their own guideline.

Comment: @boghyon, yes, I know that, thanks~ Since out team did not have guidline yet, I just use UI5 guideline for consistency~ And understand it makes more easy for me to read the API and source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variant is a data type that does not declare a variable explicit. i.e. variant is to be used instead of other data types to handle data more flexible. i.e. vMessage can reference either to `sap.ui.core.message.Message` or `sap.ui.core.message.Message[]`. it can be variant 1. the `sap.ui.core.message.Message` object or it can be variant 2. the `sap.ui.core.message.Message[]` array. variant means that it can contain any data type: vVariable could contain any data type. sVariable is supposed to contain a string. oVariable is supposed to contain an object. in regard to the hungarian notation in javascript.